# Delete image id for deleted image

Tags: mysql, database, image, opencart, plesk

I deleted some images from my ftp folder but in my SQL database the products are still linking to those images so in my store they turn in blank images.
I would like to know it there is a way for my database to check if the files exist and if not clear the field on the image table.

Hope I could explain myself a little bit.

Edit: The questioner, who is using phpmyadmin, advises (see comments) that 'It's a database from a website. I use plesk so I think it's MySQL.'

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. You would probably be best to write a program in your language of choice to do this (assuming you can't just restore the missing images from a backup, of course). Alternatively, use some sql along the lines of " select concat('@if not exist ',illustration,' echo ',illustration,' absent') from webcatalogue where illustration is not null and illustration <>'' ", output it to a .bat file, and run it from the image folder, then clear the image fields manually (if there aren't too many). It would help incidentally if you identified the exact RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Hello Mandy and thank you for your reply. I basicly never used SQL and i'm trying to get things to work by myself so i don't understand much of what you said. I'm using PHPMyadmin but downloading SSMS at the moment.
I found this on the web https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30527/sql-server-how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-directory/ but don't know where to apply it

Comment: Hi, the key fact is which database platform you are using. SSMS and the link you quote both make it sound to be SQL Server, but are you sure? Because phpmyadmin makes it sound to be MySQL. The answer to this will really affect the recommendations.

Comment: Its a database from a website. I use plesk so i think its MySQL.

Comment: Be clear that there is no point in trying SSMS or the stored procedure at the tech-recipes link as both are SQL Server related. Please edit the tags on your question to show mysql and especially plesk, which should get more knowledgeable people engaged with this.

Comment: P.S. I have submitted edits adding mysql and plesk tags (and removing sql as we are only allowed 5 altogether) but my edit needs peer reviewing so may take a while to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in OpenCart framework, like this:

Open this file:

```
admin\controller\common\header.php
```

Find:

```
$data['logged'] = true;
```

Add after:

```
// Select all products with image
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id, image FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE image <> ''");
if ($query->num_rows) {
    foreach ($query->rows as $product) {
        // If product image does not exists, update product and set image to ''
        if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $product['image'])) {
            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET image = '' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product['product_id'] . "'" );
        }
    }
}
```

Now visit a page in your admin panel.

Note: you may need to clear your modifications cache. go to extensions / modifications / click on the refresh button.

After you did it, you don't need above code, remove it from your header.php